# After resolving conflicts how to 'git add' all the resolved files

Tags: git

So one thing that happens to every now and then, is:

- doing a `git merge <some-branch>`
- have multiple conflicts
- resolve those conflicts manually using a text editor
- git add all the individual files

I want to ask about is this last step. I know I can do a `git add .`, but I may have some loose files laying around that I do not want added to version control.

Is there a command, alias, or some way you know to only add the previously conflicting files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have some *files* that you don’t want added, but don’t have any such non-conflicting changes, then you can use `git add --update`:

```
git add -u .
```

From [`git-add(1)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html):

> #### `-u`, `--update`
>
> Update the index just where it already has an entry matching
>   `<pathspec>`. This removes as well as modifies index entries to
>   match the working tree, but adds no new files.
>
> If no `<pathspec>` is given when `-u` option is used, all tracked files
>   in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used
>   to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories).